# Showing Arabic script inside tcblisting (tcolorbox)

Tags: polyglossia, tcolorbox, arabic

in this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
,escapeinside={*}{*}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\LaTeX * \textarabic{كلمة عربية}*
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={style=tcblatex,escapeinside={*}{*}}}

\LaTeX  * %\textarabic{كلمة عربية}*
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

with `lstlisting` environment i can show arabic text using listing option `escapeinside`,  But in contrast, with `tcblisting` if i remove `%` sign before `\textarabic`  I get an error alert

> ! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain
>   the Arabic

any idea to fix this ?

Comment: Off-topic, but I’m just wondering, why is the 1.3 scale is applied to Amiri?

Comment: I cannot test your MWE since I don't have the Amiri font. I can just guess that font settings made by `style=tcblatex` could be the problem. So, please, try if `listing options={language=[LaTeX]TeX,escapeinside={*}{*}}` solve the problem.

Comment: My MWE work fine with `listing option={langage= TeX,escapeinside={*}{*}}` ([LaTeX]TeX cause error ...!Package Listings Error: File 'T(.tex)' not found), thanks for @ThomasF.Sturm and @KhaledHosny

Comment: we can use `listing option={language={[LaTeX]TeX},escapeinside={*}{*}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this MWE you can show arabic script in tcblisting

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,escapeinside={*}{*}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\LaTeX * \textarabic{كلمة عربية}*
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,listing options={language={[LaTeX]TeX},escapeinside={*}{*}}}

\LaTeX  * \textarabic{كلمة عربية}*
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

and the result
[image]